# No static method getInstance(Landroid/content/Context;) Crash App when build Android APK in React Native Project

Tags: android, react-native

**Issue:**
Build Android APK of React Native Project that include package react-native-branch version 5.4.0 will cause crash app.

**Logcat:**

```
2023-08-02 09:13:14.958 21590-21590/staging.klubcoin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: staging.klubcoin, PID: 21590
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getInstance(Landroid/content/Context;)Lio/branch/referral/Branch; in class Lio/branch/referral/Branch; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.branch.referral.Branch' appears in /data/app/~~I5cmDpCmKQePbQPBCrzxzA==/staging.klubcoin-GsaHiZyd32cGjYRnZFrsYA==/base.apk!classes7.dex)
        at io.branch.rnbranch.RNBranchModule.setupBranch(RNBranchModule.java:746)
        at io.branch.rnbranch.RNBranchModule.initSession(RNBranchModule.java:123)
        at com.liquichain.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1436)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8024)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3459)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2068)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7703)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, then accept it

Comment: It is actually normal to do so, stackoverflow itself encourages it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** Upgrade react-native-branch to version 5.9.0 will resolve the problem